# Pseudo-element not rendering on input in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to change the background image of checkbox.

However, it does not seem to work in Internet Explorer. It works in Chrome, though.

Any ideas what I need to do to make it work in Internet Explorer?

```
input[type=checkbox]:before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    text-indent: -1px;
    color: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    background-image: url('../lib/dist/images/checkbox_d87b252c.gif');
}
```